# Apache redirects all hosts to external url

Tags: 12.04, apache2

Apache suddenly began to redirect all my local hosts ( ex. test.dev ) to external url. How to trace that, or any solution pls.

Comment: Could you show us the content of the `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: `order hosts,bind
multi on`, thats all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using a local DNS server, you need to specify the local hosts in the `/etc/hosts` file. Just add

```
127.0.0.1      test.dev
```

as a new line to that file. Maybe you have to restart the Apache, but then `test.dev` should point to your local machine again.